Google Sheet: if condition throwing false while result is true

Google Sheet: if condition throwing false while result is true
i have Google sheet that i built to reconcile transactions and numbers
i have completely done, except where if condition throws FALSE as a result in (red) where actually the result is correct formula is as follows
I = SUM(B41:D41)-SUM(G41:H41)
K = I41=0
Sample
382162854   110 0.66    0.1 4       110 0.76    0   0   FALSE
i have attached image for better visualisation

Maybe they're rounded values, so the difference isn't exactly 0?

I agree with @Martín; apparently, the result from SUM(B41:D41)-SUM(G41:H41) isn't a true '0' value, thus, it returns 'false'. I conducted a test log to a single cell with the formula in column I using the Apps Script. This revealed that it isn't a true '0' value but as a rounded whole number '0'.

The number in cell I41 looks like a zero in the number format you are using, but it is not exactly zero. This is a floating point number issue that is caused by the subtraction operation in the formula in cell I41.
To make the formula work, strip the least significant digits, like this:
=round(I41, 9) = 0

See Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?.
